# Tips for embedding html into another site

Tags: javascript, html, twitter, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

Currently, I use Buffer (http://bufferapp.com) as a browser extension and noticed that it stopped working on Twitter recently. If you do not know, this extension adds a 'Buffer' button to many social media websites. Twitter made another UI change, and the Buffer extension no longer add its button to the bottom of tweets.

Thinking that I might do something along these lines in the future (i.e., adding content to other websites via a browser extension), I wanted to know if there are any standard practices when doing so. Are there good tips to avoid this breakage over time? I know its simply impossible to guarantee that the origin site won't break your code, but I hope there are some thoughts on how I can mitigate against it.

Thanks for any thoughts or insights!

Answer (score 0):

copy paste this addon and edit in the "addDiv" and removeDiv functions.
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ghforkable/

this addon inects javascript into github. you can change it to twitter

https://github.com/Noitidart/ghForkable

if you need more help let me know i can change this to specifically insert on twitter in 10min

Comment: Thank you for the link, I'll check it out. I was more curious about best practices. Meaning, if I were to go ahead and try something like this, what can I do to prevent myself from breakage when the host site changes its HTML or CSS structure?

Comment: when host changes site only thing you can do is update your addon